# Sphinx complex queries with mix of AND/OR

Tags: sphinx

I've been looked around and have no luck on this.

So I have a complex query to sphinx and wondering if I could do complex query of SQL like this

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (categoryid in (17,18,19, 20) OR merchantid in (110,112,335)) AND brandid NOT in (20, 30, 40,50);
```

I know OR is working with SetSelect with

```
$s->SetSelect('*, IN(categoryid, 17,18 19) OR IN(merchantid,110,112, 335) AS test');
$s->SetFilter('test', array(1), true);
$s->query("", "index");
```

NOT query could be done as individual query

```
$s->SetSelect('*, IN(brandid,20,30,40,50 AS nottest');
$s->SetFilter('nottest', array(1));
$s->query("", "index");
```

But how should I combine both in one query

Answer (score 0):

For the 'OR' you use the same techique from setSelect

Something like

```
SELECT *, (categoryid in (17,18,19, 20) OR merchantid in (110,112,335)) AS test 
FROM Table 
WHERE test = 1 AND brandid NOT in (20, 30, 40,50);
```